# Get the last row with condition from group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm scratching my head to figure out how can I retrieve the last row of each group by column in MySQL 5.6, that matches a specific value. For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE `djs` (
  `dj_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `djs` (`dj_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Jack'),
(2, 'Sam');

CREATE TABLE `shows` (
  `show_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dj_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `show_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `show_started` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `show_ended` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `shows` (`show_id`, `dj_id`, `show_active`, `show_started`, `show_ended`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2020-06-07 12:05:41', '2020-06-07 14:44:48'),
(2, 2, 1, '2020-06-07 12:05:41', '2020-06-07 14:55:48'),
(4, 1, 0, '2020-06-07 15:43:50', '2020-06-07 15:43:50'),
(5, 2, 1, '2020-06-07 15:58:51', '2020-06-07 16:00:51'),
(6, 2, 0, '2020-06-07 16:01:51', '2020-06-07 16:34:51');
```

Let's say I'm grouping this table by the dj_id, so, in this case, we'd have 2 rows (from dj_id's 1 and 2).

I want to know what query should I use to get the last row of each dj_id that has a show_active set to 1 (or true), so the result would be this:

```
show_id x dj_id x show_active x show_started
1       x 1     x 1           x 2020-06-07 12:05:41
5       x 2     x 1           x 2020-06-07 15:58:51
```

EDIT: Provided [an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46bbe6/1/0) to illustrate the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find the row you want. For example:

```
select *
from `shows`
where (`dj_id`, `show_started`) in (
  select `dj_id`, max(`show_started`)
  from `shows`
  where `show_active` = 1
  group by `dj_id`
)
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4JEHRP3eTg4ZB1sxcnm3Rd/1).

**Edit for performance:**

If the query is slow, maybe the right indexes are not in place. I would try creating the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on shows (show_active, dj_id, show_started);

create index ix2 on shows (dj_id, show_started);
```

The second one is questionable. Try using the first one alone, and then see if the second one helps further.

Comment: Hello! You've nailed it! By the way, how important is the MAX(`show_started`) part?

Comment: I mean, perhaps using a MAX(show_id) would be more precise as it's unique and uses auto_increment?

Comment: @MateusMelo It depends on which column you use to decide which row is the "last one". I assumed it was time based, but you could use the id, if you think that's right.

Comment: @TheImpaler right! For some reason, this query is taking up to 30 seconds to complete in my production server... I think I'll have to use another approach.